# Resize shape as per last filled column

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to change the width of the shape in this Excel in the attached picture. The size would be determined by the last column that contains data, in this case column E.

I have added the following code:

```
Sub UsedRange_Example_Column()
Dim LastColumn As Long
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    LastColumn = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Column
End With

iCol = 0
For i = 3 To LastColumn
    iCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).ColumnWidth + iCol
Next i

ActiveSheet.Shapes("Shape 37").Width = (iCol) * 5.72
End Sub
```

However, I am unable to determine the multiplier which I should use to change the size cause 5.72 is not giving me the correct results. Please note that column B is 1" in size.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your shape starts in col B, perhaps something like this. I have not specified the Top of the shape.

```
Sub UsedRange_Example_Column()

Dim LastColumn As Long

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    LastColumn = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Column
End With

With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Shape 37")
    .Left = Range("B1").Left
    .Width = Range("B1").Resize(, LastColumn - 1).Width
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to the width of your range in question:

```
Sub UsedRange_Example_Column()

    Dim dataRng As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set dataRng = ws.UsedRange

    With ws.Shapes("Shape 37")
        .Left = dataRng.Left
        .Width = dataRng.Width
    End With

End Sub
```

You should get out of the habit of using `ActiveSheet` whenever possible (most of the time it is). Always declare your worksheets as this can avoid *many* debugging nightmares.